# Cross sectional area of impinging streams (2 dimensional)

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, geometry, scattering-cross-section

I am trying to calculate the cross sectional area of the impingement zone created by  two equal, two-dimensional streams impinging upon one another.  The attached diagram shows Stream 1 impinging with equal stream, Stream 2, at an angle of $2\beta$.  All quantities on the diagram except $y$ are known.  I need to calculate $y$ so that I can then calculate the cross sectional area of the trapezoid created by the dashed lines (on three sides) and $y$ on the left hand side.  Here are the equations that I currently have:

$$s_f = s_i(\frac{Z+cos\beta}{Z^2})$$

$$s_B = s_i(\frac{Z-cos\beta}{Z^2})$$

$$s_f + s_B = \frac{2s_i}{Z}$$

$$X = \frac{s_i}{sin\beta}$$

Eqn 3 is simply the sum of Eqns. 1 and 2. At any impingement angle $2\beta$, Z is a known constant, but $Z$ does vary with $2\beta$.

Is there any way to solve this with the information given?

There is perhaps one more piece of information that might help.  If $2\beta = 180^o$, then $s_f = s_b$.  In this case it would seem that y = $s_b$.  But I'm not sure that this is correct.

My initial thoughts are that $y = 2s_i$ or $y=2s_i-s_b$.  I've been trying to figure this out for some time now and it seems that I've only succeeded in confusing myself.

If there isn't enough information in order to determine $y$, then suggestions on what additional information is needed are very welcome.

Note: On the diagream $s_i$ is the length of the line with arrows on both ends not the dashed line that is near it.

[image]